Sankey Diagram for Wireless sensor network, accurate?
I've designed a Sankey diagram to depict security in Wireless Body Area Networks for my thesis. It's the first time I see such a diagram used for security. I need your help.
Could you check its accuracy and suggest improvements?

Thanks for your insights!

Hi & welcome Moh. The width of the channels is proportional to the flow of 'stuff'.  How did you determine this? E.g. how do security and energy share a common metric?

The flow separation between Energy and Computation is especially problematic, as computation requires energy, and a variable amount thereof according to implementation. HMAC is not encryption (it's cryptography). I don't see how NFC relates to Confidentiality (it's a communication mean, reasonably easy to eavesdrop, and encryption if any is on top of NFC, typically not part of it). Incidentally, "Computaion" is a "t" short.

Thanks for the point @PaulUszak. I agree that there is no common metric but the main goal is to compare different part of this flow chart.
I was thinking that when one is designing a system how much they want to spend on each part and how much it would cost at the end.
do you think that this a good diagram to show that.

Awesome points you have mentioned @fgrieu. I was thinking to rename some of those nodes to the following:
Computation -> latency,
Encryption - > Cryptography,
HMAC -> MAC.
do you think about it now?
would this be a useful diagram overall to convey the point?

I can see what you're attempting here. You're (via Sankey) relating various components of a wide area network that is secured cryptographically.
But my understanding of Sankey is that the channel flow (width) is a homogeneous 'thing' like cardio vascular flow volume, profit within  bank departments or French troop movements (yes I had to look it up too).
The transitional states still have to have a common metric/language  (tonnage, joules, iterations e.t.c). Near field communication is a protocol, availability is commonly stated in percent, authentication is a process and energy is some form of Joulage/Wattage/Voltage/foot poundage. I thus can't see a numeric and consistent way to determine the width of the interconnecting channels between nodes.
It seems that your diagram is at a level above what is generally categorised as a Sankey one.
EDIT.
This follows Moh's comment:-

"I was thinking that when one is designing a system how much they want to spend on each part and how much it would cost at the end. "

Now that would be a Sankey diagram.  There is a common metric of 'cost' that allows a proportional determination of channel widths and node relationships.  So ironically, one channel could go from BUDGET at the left to ENERGY on the right as a network consumes a financial amount of energy. NFC would fit in as the sub-cost of the inductive coil parts, but not sure how to determine the (monetary) cost of KEY SHARING unless you figure developers' implementation costs (as a leaf node of the SOFTWARE branch).
It might look something akin to:-


I agree that this is not a Sankey diagram. I assume that I have to remove the NFC from the chart.

But overall would this be helpful to mention that in WBAN application cryptography is more important than the other aspect of security, a relative comparison.
I wanted to also emphasize that each part of this will end up consuming energy!
